# How to convert a SqlServer DateTime to universal time using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a database with DateTime fields that are currently stored in local time.  An upcoming project will require all these dates to be converted to universal time.  Rather than writing a c# app to convert these times to universal time, I'd rather use available sqlserver/sql features to accurately convert these dates to universal time so I only need an update script.  To be accurate, the conversion would need to account for Daylight savings time fluctuations, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A User Defined Function would allow you to write an SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT toUTC([MyDateColumn], [MyTimeZoneColumn]) FROM [MyTable]
```

Then you get universal times back from the server without a lot of ugly syntax in the query itself.  Now you could build the UDF for this with regular SQL similar to what Chris posted, but SQL Server 2005 and later will let you build the UDF using CLR (.Net: C# optional) instead.  It has much better support for dates and can do a better job taking timezones and daylight savings time into account.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Doesn't have anything built in for this.

Two ways would be the `C# application` (you mentioned you don't want) or writing a really complicated update statement with something like:

```
UtcDate = DATEADD(hour, CASE WHEN OriginalDate BETWEEN x AND y THEN 4 
WHEN OriginalDate BETWEEN x2 AND y2 THEN 5 ... END, OriginalDate)
```

Note - I'd recommend the `C# app` plus something like [TZ4Net](http://www.babiej.demon.nl/Tz4Net/main.htm) to handle the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

check out the convert function and the getutcdate function?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link from CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL2005_time_zones.aspx) - it does exactly what you want: take a date and a time zone, pass them to a UDF, and get the date in UTC or any other time zone.

IMPORTANT: Check the comments of that article - the author wasn't allowed to revise the article after a certain point, and there is an updated version of the code used for the UDFs in the comments that addresses some issues not found in the original article code.

ALSO IMPORTANT: Don't use this for querying large data sets. It's perfectly fine for a one-time load into a database, or for returning a UTC date for a single row (like a user login table or what have you.)

If you want performance, the only really acceptable method for time zone conversion is to have a lookup table that handles every possible time zone conversion for every single hour in a year, with a case statement to handle rollovers between years (ie December 31 - January 1 or vice versa.) Yes, the table is huge, but the query performance is nil.